# Javascript: IE event.preventDefault is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My code works fine in FF/Chrome/Everything except IE(failed in both 7/8, didn't bother going furthur down). Due to restrictions, I cannot use jQuery and am hard-coding the Javascript. The issue is with IE, I am getting "preventDefault is null or not an object". Hoping one of you has the answer, and here's relevant code:

AddEvent Method:

```
function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {  
  if ( obj.attachEvent ) {  
    obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;  
    obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}  
    obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );  
  } else  
    obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );  
};
```

Event handler throwing error:

```
function mousedown(e){  
  if(e.preventDefault){  
    e.preventDefault();  
  } else {  
    e.returnValue = false;  
    e.cancelBubble=true;  
  }
  //Processing   
};
```

Also DOCTYPE and charset are both set on the calling HTML page. Any ideas would be appreciated. The error is thrown in the if statement for the mousedown method.

EDIT:

Due to the fact that grabbing window.event did "fix" the main issue, I discovered the problem was a different section of code. Basically I am adding a  element ontop of a pre-placed element, and then registering mousedown/mousemove events to that div. When firing the event on the `<div>`, THAT'S where the error is thrown.

Could this be something due to the fact that I have events registered to 2

```
rect = document.createElement('div');  
rect.className='square';  
rect.id='chooser_rectangle';  
rect.style.left=initx+'px';  
rect.style.top=inity+'px';  

addEvent(rect,"mousemove",mousemove);  
addEvent(rect,"mousedown",mousedown);
```

Comment: there's got to be something else going on here. your two js methods work fine for a quick demo i set up and tried with IE8. can you most a more complete example with reproducable error?

Comment: Have you tried checking `typeof e` and `typeof e.preventDefault`?

Comment: The example code as is would not cause the error "event.preventDefault is null or not an object". For one you don't reference "event" in your handler, but rather "e".

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps the OP did something like `if(e.preventDefault())` instead of `if(e.preventDefault)`.  I can't see why `preventDefault` being `null` should be a problem for using it in an if statement.

Comment: do you have 2 divs with the same id? there's still not enough here to put together an example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Moot point, if anyone is finding this Q late in the day... you should be checking for `addEventListener` before `attachEvent` since IE9 supports both.

Answer (score 6):

In IE the event object is not passed as the first argument to an event handler. Instead it is a global variable:

```
function mousedown(e){
 var evt = e || window.event; // IE compatibility
 if(evt.preventDefault){  
  evt.preventDefault();  
 }else{  
  evt.returnValue = false;  
  evt.cancelBubble=true;  
 }
 //Processing   
};
```

Comment: it is when you use `attachEvent`.

Comment: Figured it was something along the lines of passing in the wrong event. Thanks, this has been killing me for the better part of an hour now

Comment: @avrx if you're having problems with your event object, saying f*** it and grabbing `window.event` is not the way to fix it.

Comment: If this was the problem, shouldn't you be getting an error about `e` being undefined?  The fact that it objects to `preventDefault` being `null` makes me think the OP wrote something other than what we're being shown.  `if(null)` wouldn't produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

IE has a different event model to other browsers (even IE8). In IE you would call this to do the same thing:

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

You need to determine what the browser supports and call the correct method. So first check if event.returnValue is set, if so then call it, otherwise call preventDefault().