# form handler doesn't seem to work always

Tags: jquery

Really weird, the following codes seems to work *sometimes* It always worked (on my Macbook Pro) and other computers, but when I tested today at my university (IE) it only showed the message 'Success' without handling the action in `process-mailing.php` (which works btw)

```
$("form#mailing").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('process-mailing.php',$("#mailing").serialize(),function(data){
        $("&lt;div class='form-message-succeed'>Succesvol toegevoegd!</div>").hide().appendTo("#mailing").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#mail").add("#go-mailing").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});




<form id="mailing" method="post" action="process.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>E-mail</legend>
        <label for="mail" id="mail-label">Je mail adres&lt;/label>
        <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="voorbeeld@domein.com">
        <label for="go-mailing" id="gol">Voeg toe&lt;/label>
        <input type="submit" class="go" id="go-mailing" value="Voeg Toe">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Can it be that this works in certain browsers only? And how can I make it work everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE the event object is not passed as the first argument to an event handler. Instead it is a global variable

solution and quoted from:
[Javascript: IE event.preventDefault is null or not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677748/javascript-ie-event-preventdefault-is-null-or-not-an-object)