# prevent a link from redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link in my page, and I want to prevent this link to redirect me to the link in the href attribute.

I tried as the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('#logout-link').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('href'),
            success : function(data){
                $('#login-loader').hide();
                        location.reload(true);
            },
            error   : function(){
                $('#error-login').replaceWith('<div id="error-login" class="msg fail"><p>Une erreur a été rencontrée lors du deconnexion!</p></div>');
            }
        });


    });
});
```

But it stills redirect me tho the other page.

How can prevent a link from redirecting to another page ?

Comment: try adding `return false` at the end of the `click` handler

Comment: usually when `event.preventDefault`, does not work it means there is some javascript error that prevents it from being executed, check your console for errors, or make sure your link is actually being selected by your jquery selector

Comment: @RC. Yes I already tried that, it didn't worked :/

Comment: @PatrickEvans I've checked my console, and there is no error in it, in the same js file I prevent a form submitting, if there is some error that code which prevents the form won't be work either.

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU, are you confusing `location.reload(true);` as a redirect? that is reloading the page, if you are not wanting the page to reload, take that out.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I do want the page to reload, thanks by the way :)

Comment: Have you tried severals browsers ? which jQuery version are you using ? ... any fiddle available ? Is this the only handler attached ?

Comment: In some IE (7,8,?) preventDefault is undefined - see answer by slebetman  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677748/javascript-ie-event-preventdefault-is-null-or-not-an-object

Comment: You have everything correct in this code. Does your link have an id of "logout-link" and is it the only element with that id?

Comment: Also, is this dynamic content? If the element is not on the page when it loads, you will need to use `$(document).on('click', '#logout-link', function (e){...});`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `return false;` instead of `event.preventDefault();` But use it after ajax call.

Comment: Are you sure that the JS is working. Try with `alert()` to confirm. or else instead of using `$(function(){` at the beginning, try with `$(document).ready(function(){`.

Comment: And in Angular (in case someone needs it), one needs to go: *(click)="false"*.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify hyperlink href like below. This method doesn't need any code in JQuery.

```
<a id="logout-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Just a note. None of the solutions on this page works reliably in IE on  WM5/6 which unfortunately is still in use in industry environments.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 $(document).on("click", '#logout-link', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // your ajax call here 
    });
```